# Is there any way to join Inkle (.js, JSON, .ink) with Android Studio projeсt?

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, inkle-ink

I'm new here, really need to find the answer cause there's a lack of info about this little problem. I made text adventure game in Ink (Inkle editor for interactive novels). I've been trying to "plug" the story (exported for web in JS, HTML and CSS) in Android Studio. Made it, tried it on phone (it works), then I wanted to make a menu for the game.

So the question is - how can I join menu (made in Java) in AStudio to Ink novel that was exported to AS projest (by cordova and so on) that consists of JS and HTML?
Cause the Ink game starts as the app starts - from the beginning at the HTML that do:

```
<script src="ink.js"></script>
<script src="Chapter 1.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>`
```

I want to start from the Java code of AStudio (menu of the game), them move to the story (JS code) by tapping on the "start" button. (I also want to add saving/loading of the game state further. In C# it was something like that: `string savedJson = _inkStory.state.ToJson() _inkStory.state.LoadJson(savedJson)` as I did it in Unity)

Hope u can help...

[image: App's files tree in Android Studio]